# Multithreaded Application and Potential Memory Leak (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, memory-leaks, task

I have a console application that runs jobs in a scheduled fashion. 
A job does 2 things:

1-) Run a SQL statement 
2-) E-mail the result of that statement

If I run the job in sequential form, everything works as expected, a job runs, memory consumption increases during the operation and then memory is released, however if I run the jobs in parallel, using the task parallel library, after all the jobs finish, memory consumption stays much higher compared to the sequential option and additional jobs also continues to increase memory consumption.

To be more specific I used the following test cases:

Sequential: (After loop is completed and GC is collected explicitly for test purposes memory consumption is around 55 megabytes)

```
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        var job = new BIJob(reportData);
        job.Execute();
    }
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
}
```

Parallel:(After loop is completed and GC is collected explicitly for test purposes memory consumption is around 85 megabytes)

```
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        Task jobRunTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var job = new BIJob(reportData);
            job.Execute();

        });
    }
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
}
```

There is approximately 30 megabytes difference in memory consumption after 45 iterations and that extra memory is not being collected in the parallel version.

What might be causing this kind of behaviour? Any ideas/comments is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that your `job.Execute()` can handle a multithreaded scenario?

Answer (score 1):

When you're performing multiple operations in parallel you'll need to store enough memory to work on each of those parallel operations, rather than having the working set of just one in memory at a time.  You also have additional threads, each of which are going to consume memory.

The memory for those operations won't be able to be reclaimed *until they actually finish*.  You're just *starting* the operations in your loop, not waiting for them to finish, so they are not necessarily even eligible for collection whenever it is that you're checking on them.  If you wait for all of the operations to *actually finish* then they will be *eligible* for collection, although the GC is of course free to wait as long as it wants to *actually collect* them.

Comment: Hi Servy,I modified my parallel code to wait for tasks to finsh like below; however is still around same then all tasks complete:

`List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        Task jobRunTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var job = new BIJob(reportData);
            job.Execute();

        });
    tasks.Add(jobRunTask);
    }
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
}
     Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
`

Comment: @erdem The memory becomes *eligible* for collection after the tasks complete, it won't necessarily be collected immediately though, and the thread pool threads created won't be torn down immediately after you finish using them; they'll be released slowly over time as they idle.  You shouldn't even be worrying about any of this in the first place.  You should only be concerning yourself with such issues if you're actually having problems with your memory, and you clearly are not.

Comment: The thing is i use the application as a service and I watch the memory usage daily. Memory consumption seems to be going up in small amounts everyday after a batch of jobs run in parallel (around 10 megabytes) and it never goes down to where it was before. (I think by that time those task related resources should have been released) It seems like in long term this may cause crash problems.

Comment: @erdem Profile the memory, and look for objects that you expect to be eligible for collection that aren't.

Comment: I have used some profilers but couldn't find a solution to the problem. What I wonder is if the situation I have (increase in memory usage everyday in small amounts) is an indication of memory leak or it might be related to tasks being not released for clr internal reasons even after a long time (days in my case). Should I consider something explicit to release tasks.

Comment: @erdem If you profiled your code then you'd know exactly what objects weren't being freed, and you'd be able to see whether or not its the tasks, or something else.  When you know what's actually the problem *then* you can start looking for ways to solve it.  As it is you're trying to solve a problem that you don't you don't even know that you have.

Answer (score 0):

The Task parallel library will simply keep some of the threads it creates around in case it will need them later because creating new Threads is a relatively costly operation (both in terms of memory and CPU).

Regarding the memory-leak: As long as there is no stress on resources there is no reason for the threadpool used by the TPL to free any threads.
If you want to test for a memory-leak you can simply increase the count of your loop. There should be no difference in memory-usage after say looping 1000 times or 1000000 times.

Comment: This is the thread pool, not the TPL, and also note that the threads will be freed after they've been idling for a while.

Comment: The TPL by Default uses the thread pool. And yes, of course it will free them after a while.

Comment: Yes, my point is that this isn't behavior specific to the TPL, it's more generalized than that, the TPL simply uses the thread pool, which has this behavior.

Comment: Well the question was, why he is experiencing this behavior, not which internal component is responsible for it ;)